# How do I retrieve two values from the same column based on two different conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Table name: Route

```
Route_ID (int)
Route_From (int)
Route_To (int)
```

Table name: Stations

```
Station_ID (int),
Name (char)
```

Values of `Route_From`, `Route_To`, and `Station_ID` are the same.

I want to know how to retrieve two values from stations.name for two different conditions. For example, something like

```
 select s.name, s.name from stations s, route r, 
 where route_from=1 and
 route_to=3;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: wat do u mean by two values from stations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
SELECT
    Route.Route_ID,
    fromStation.Name,
    toStation.Name
FROM
    Route
    LEFT JOIN Stations AS fromStation
        ON Route.Route_From =fromStation.Station_ID
    LEFT JOIN Stations AS toStation
        ON Route.Route_To  =toStation.Station_ID
WHERE 
    Route.Route_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
select s1.name as route_from, s2.name as route_to from route r
left join stations s1 on r.route_from = s1.Station_ID
left join stations s2 on r.route_to = s2.Station_ID
where Route_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Route.Route_ID,
fromStation.Name,
toStation.Name
FROM
Route
LEFT JOIN Stations AS fromStation
    ON Route.Route_From =fromStation.Station_ID
LEFT JOIN Stations AS toStation
    ON Route.Route_To  =toStation.Station_ID
WHERE 
Route.Route_ID = 1;
```